# Will we know when people start getting jobs through careers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, jobs

I'm sure it isn't easy to implement, has privacy implications, etc., but I think it'd be really neat if Jeff's Angels could somehow broadcast when careers was successfully used to place someone at a job.

Perhaps a simple running tracker of "*X programmers placed at dream jobs so far...*".

Of course this would depend on people opting in and reporting when they received an offer, etc., but I think it'd be really great (and great promotion for the service) if there was some way to announce/broadcast when the service has actually helped someone out.

Even if it's a simple blog post from time to time - as a prospective customer, I'm really interested to know if/when careers is helping people get jobs.

Comment: is Jeff's Angels the official name now?

Comment: Absolutely. And if you believe that, I have a rock that keeps tigers away for sale.

Comment: -1 just because you shortened 'through' to 'thru'. Are we in high school?

Answer (score -1):

Pay attention to Twitter. Those of us that have gotten jobs from Careers (yes, myself included) usually thank the StackOverflow team there.

...oh, and I'm loving the job by the way.

Comment: any suggestions what to search for?